# Angular rxjs : force response to be null if http.get can't find the json file

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

In my Angular app ; i'm used to get data from static json file ;

like this :

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() { 
    this.http.get('/assets/myfile.json').subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
  }

}
```

In some scnenarios , `myfile.json` may to not be present

(and it's something needed for other purposes)

in this case ***i don't want to get this error*** :

> HttpErrorResponse : Http failure during parsing for
>   https://localhost:4201/assets/myfile.json

but simply , i want to get a `null` **respionse**

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: You can use `catchError()` and and return `of(null)` or rethrow the error depending on some condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can use the [catchError](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) operator like this:

```
getData() { 
    this.http.get('/assets/myfile.json')
      .pipe(catchError(error => of(null)))
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  }
```